# NumPy error while implementing feature engineering functions on array

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, feature-engineering

In the below-given code, I was implementing `autofeat` library for feature engineering. But when I ran the code in google colab, It gave an error, as stated below.

```
import autofeat as af
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
data = load_boston()
x = data.data
y= data.target
clf = af.AutoFeatRegressor(x,y)
clf.fit_transform(x,y)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-7f5a5bb453d3> in <module>()
      5 y= data.target
      6 clf = af.AutoFeatRegressor(x,y)
----> 7 clf.fit_transform(x,y)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

[reference code tutorial](https://analyticsindiamag.com/guide-to-automatic-feature-engineering-using-autofeat/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your error is when defining the clf. You don't need to specify x and y. It seems to mess up the thing.

Try with : `clf = af.AutoFeatRegressor()`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I'm accepting your answer in 4 min, you please upvote my question!

Comment: 2min left, i;ll accept your answer, and thanks a lot for upvote